# Setting a test case variable in all the test cases in a Katalon Studio test suite, from the test suite

Tags: katalon-studio, test-suite

This question is probably an ongoing source of complaining about Katalon Studio, but...

I have this test suite, called `Discount`, with 42 test cases in it. Each test case accept, as variable, a `practiceProfile`, with the same default value: `com.xxx.profiles.PracticeProfile.SMD_DEFAULT`.

Unfortunately, somewhere along the multiple runs of that test suite, I caused a blocker of a bug on the AUT, and can't run any more tests with the default profile.

I wish to install some control, in the test suite, via which I can change the `practiceProfile` passed to all the test cases.

I do have the following `PracticeProfiles`, and I know I could change it from here:

```
public final class PracticeProfiles {
    public static final PracticeProfile SMD_DEFAULT = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.DEMO_PRACTICE, PracticeURLs.DEMO_PRACTICE);
    public static final PracticeProfile SMD_IMPERIAL = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.IMPERIAL_MEDICAL_CENTER_II, PracticeURLs.IMPERIAL_MEDICAL_CENTER_II);
    public static final PracticeProfile PARAGON_DEFAULT = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.PARAGON, PracticeNames.PARAGON_DEMO_PRACTICE, PracticeURLs.PARAGON_DEMO_PRACTICE);

    // the MDG practices
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_1 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_1, PracticeURLs.MDG_1, NPINumbers.MDG_1);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_10 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_10, PracticeURLs.MDG_10, NPINumbers.MDG_10);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_18 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_18, PracticeURLs.MDG_18, NPINumbers.MDG_18);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_19 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_19, PracticeURLs.MDG_19, NPINumbers.MDG_19);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_20 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_20, PracticeURLs.MDG_20, NPINumbers.MDG_20);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_21 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_21, PracticeURLs.MDG_21, NPINumbers.MDG_21);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_22 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_22, PracticeURLs.MDG_22, NPINumbers.MDG_22);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_23 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_23, PracticeURLs.MDG_23, NPINumbers.MDG_23);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_24 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_24, PracticeURLs.MDG_24, NPINumbers.MDG_24);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_27 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_27, PracticeURLs.MDG_27, NPINumbers.MDG_27);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_28 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_28, PracticeURLs.MDG_28, NPINumbers.MDG_28);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_40 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_40, PracticeURLs.MDG_40, NPINumbers.MDG_40);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_41 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_41, PracticeURLs.MDG_41, NPINumbers.MDG_41);
    public static final PracticeProfile MDG_50 = new PracticeProfile(OrganizationNames.SMD_BETA, PracticeNames.MDG_50, PracticeURLs.MDG_50, NPINumbers.MDG_50);
}
```

however, doing so would be incorrect.

Just a shot in the dark, is there any way I could have the test suite drive the test cases like this?